# How to read a file in the app module from another module in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I can explain the question with an example,

When integrating Firebase to an Android Project. You download a google-services.json file which contains your project information. The firebase SDK on initialisation reads the contents of this file. Atleast, that is what I am assuming happens. If so, how does an external library access a file in another module(in this case, the app module).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: It's not clear what file are you trying to access you are trying to access from an external library.  Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you @JamesPoag. The dev page explains how this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) explains how the plugin works.

Everything happens at **compile** time not at runtime.  So there is no interaction between the Firebase SDK and the JSON file.  Instead the gradle plugin, activated by `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` reads the JSON file and writes a `strings.xml` file that gets merged into your application.  The Firebase SDK can then read these values with calls like `getResources().getString(R.string.google_app_id)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the official link. This part of the documentation tells what happens when the library processes the configuration file:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file 
The documentation tells "The main result of the JSON processing is to produce two XML files which you can reference as Android resources in your Java code." which is a great result, however, "How that result is achieved" seems missing. It would be great to know "How does one library module read a config file in the app module before producing the XML file".

Comment: @superus8r the file is not actually "read", Android XML resources are merged across modules and available globally at runtime. The Firebase plugin just creates a resource with an expected ID and the runtime code goes looking for it.

Comment: My apologies if my question was unclear and thank you for explanation. I understand that Android XML resources are merged across modules. However, that happens "after" the resource is produced. The main question is how to access the config file in the app module "before" producing the resources.